# Merge a list of identical data frames that have missing values in different places

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, na

Start with a list of data frames that have different values missing but are otherwise identical.

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- df4 <- head(iris)

df1[4,2] <- NA
df2[3,5] <- NA
df3[2,]  <- NA
df4[2,2] <- NA

lst <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

What is the best (fast in terms of computation speed) way to merge these data frames so that any missing values for which the information is available in at least one data frame are gone?

NOTE: preferably with only base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd `Reduce` over them and use `is.na` with `[<-` replacement.

```r
done <- Reduce(function(prev, this) {
  isna <- is.na(this)
  if (any(isna)) this[isna] <- prev[isna]
  this
}, lst)
done
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

FYI, in *this* example, all values are resolved on the second iteration. We can see this by adding `accumulate=TRUE` to see the results of each "reduction":

```r
Reduce(function(prev, this) { isna <- is.na(this); if (any(isna)) this[isna] <- prev[isna]; this; }, lst, accumulate = TRUE)
# [[1]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6          NA          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# [[2]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# [[3]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5            5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# [[4]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

If you want to "early escape" when no further imputation is required, I believe a custom `for` loop is required.

```r
for (i in seq_along(lst)[-1]) {
  message(i)
  isna <- is.na(lst[[1]])
  if (!any(isna)) { message("out!"); break(); }
  lst[[1]][isna] <- lst[[i]][isna]
}
# 2
# 3
# out!
lst[[1]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9           3          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: Thanks this gives ideas (+1). Just thinking ahead out loud: probably, as your edit shows, it could be stopped early once all the values are available. Also checking for NAs within Reduce each time can be improved, because we know which NAs disappeared after each iteration.

Comment: I just added a quick check for `any(isna)`, which should short-circuit some of the processing. I also added an early-out option in a `for` loop, same effect, likely just a little faster (if we can measure differences with samples this small). @KarolisKoncevičius